# multi viewcontroller : call variable of root controller from a sub view controller

Tags: iphone

```
//root controller
class subviewcontroller;
@rootviewcontroller:UIViewController
{
   NSInteger a;
}
```

call a in subviewcontroller
super.a=1;

system reported:

```
error：Request for member ‘a' in something not a structure or union
```

welcome any comment

interdev

Comment: Please correct your post - the code is unreadable... Just add 4 spaces before each code row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nee to make it a property and synthesize it. 
like:

In the header file

```
@property(nonatomic, assign)  NSInteger a;
```

and in the implementation file:

```
@synthesize a;
```

Hope this helps.
Thanks

Madhup

Comment: I did as above

It reported:

error:request for member 'bChanged' in something not a structure or union

Comment: sorry, it is

error: request for member 'a' in something not a structure or union

Comment: this is because you are accessing it via super which will look for 'a' into UiViewController class not into your rootviewcontroller class. If you want to set the value of a variable of rootviewcontroller you must get the reference of that.

Comment: SwitchViewController *rootController= [self.navigationController.viewControllers  objectAtIndex:1];
 
   rootController.bChanged =self.subChanged ; 

I used above codes to set the value from subchanged in subviewcontroller to the variable in root viewcontroller.
But if I set the breakpoint, I checkled the value of rootController.bChanged

has not changed.

Thanks
interdev

Comment: SwitchViewController *rootController= [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]; 

samething

Comment: Can you please check on going back to that screen , that the value of that object is getting changed or not, Note that you must be sure that index you are taking is correct.